# shiny: read text content of verbatimTextOutput

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to read the text content of a `verbatimTextOutput` element within a Shiny app as a variable?

The idea of the [sample app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zWqlS.png) below is that when the user clicks `button1`, the content of `text2` gets updated and shows whatever is in `text1` ("Hello world" in this case).

The `observeEvent` handler below generates this error : `Warning: Error in $.shinyoutput: Reading objects from shinyoutput object not allowed.` but this looked to me the closest I managed to get to a solution.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Hugo

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
    ui = basicPage(verbatimTextOutput("text1"),
                   actionButton("button1", "Read & copy text!"),
                   verbatimTextOutput("text2")),

    server = function(input, output, session) {

        output$text1 <- renderText("Hello world")
        output$text2 <- renderText("Waiting for new text...")

        observeEvent(input$button1, {
            output$text2 <- output$text1
        })
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store the output of the `text1` object to a variable and pass that variable. I would suggest that you use the `session$userData` object because it makes a part of your shiny session and you dont have to declare the variable globally. Below is the code

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(verbatimTextOutput("text1"),
                 actionButton("button1", "Read & copy text!"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("text2")),

  server = function(input, output, session) {

    output$text1 <- renderText({
      session$userData$text1 <- "Hello world"
      session$userData$text1})
    output$text2 <- renderText("Waiting for new text...")

    observeEvent(input$button1, {
      output$text2 <- renderText(session$userData$text1)
    })
  }
)
```

Comment: Thank you Dinesh. This is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyApp(
      ui = basicPage(textInput("text1","","",placeholder = "Hello World"),
                     actionButton("button1", "Read & copy text!"),
                     verbatimTextOutput("text2")),

      server = function(input, output, session) {

        text2 <- eventReactive(input$button1,{
          input$text1
        })

        output$text2 <- renderText({
          validate(
            need(input$button1,"Waiting for new text....")
          )
          text2()
        }
        )
      }
    )
```

But if you want exactly the same way as you did. So, here it is.

```
    library(shiny)

    shinyApp(
      ui = basicPage(verbatimTextOutput("text1"),
                     actionButton("button1", "Read & copy text!"),
                     verbatimTextOutput("text2")),

      server = function(input, output, session) {

        output$text1 <- renderText("Hello world")
        output$text2 <- renderText({
          validate(
            need(input$button1,"Waiting for new text...")
          )
          "Hello world"
          })
      }
    )
```

Comment: Thank you Andryas! I appreciate the two suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

### Use shinyjs

If you want to read a text on any tag with an id and save it in an input. You can use the pakage [shinyjs](https://github.com/daattali/shinyjs) and some js code to read the text and then use `Shiny.onInputChange ()` to create the input. The code below solves your problem

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

shinyApp(
  ui = basicPage(useShinyjs(),verbatimTextOutput("text1"),
                 actionButton("button1", "Read & copy text!"),
                 verbatimTextOutput("text2")),
  
  server = function(input, output, session) {
    
    output$text1 <- renderText("Hello world")
    output$text2 <- renderText("Waiting for new text...")
    
    observeEvent(input$button1, {
      runjs("var textin1=$('#text1').text();
            Shiny.onInputChange('textin1', textin1);
            ")
      output$text2 <- renderText({input$textin1})
    })
  }
)
```